# How to create this UI in Gmail Add-on using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Can someone tell me how to achieve below UI in Gmail Add-on using Google Apps Script? I tried KeyValue for the *icon with text which is clickable* and I am able to achieve that but I don't know how to put email text, next to the keyValue icon. *Right now,  I don't care about the position of the icon with counter and email text, **I want them in the same row doesn't matter left or right**.* This is my code which is just showing icon with counter on the left side but not able to add email text anywhere.

```
var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
.setHeader(
  CardService.newCardHeader()
    .setTitle('some Title')
);

 var section = CardService.newCardSection();

 var keyValue = CardService.newKeyValue()
  .setContent(getNumberOfPosts())
  .setIconUrl('https://ayz.png')
  .setOnClickAction(action);

 section.addWidget(keyValue);
 card.addSection(section);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried keyValue with setButton Method?

Comment: @Bala Yes, I tried ImageButton in KeyValue Button. Counter text will come on left side and icon on right.  But I want user email and icon with counter text, side by side.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this screenshot

[image]

I used an emoji for the eye (Add-on support emojis). Does this get you what you are looking for?

```
          settingSection.addWidget(CardService.newKeyValue()
                                      .setContent("User@email.com")
                                      .setOnClickAction(saveAction)
                                      .setButton(CardService.newTextButton()
                                                 .setText("️ 2")
                                                 .setOnClickAction(saveAction))
                                       );
```

Comment: But why adding `.setOnClickAction(saveAction)` twice.

Comment: Sorry, this was a sample from one of my projects. This lets the email and eye icon have separate actions

Comment: Well it's a good try to use Unicode emoji characters for showing images. But in my case I have to use an image. Anyway thank you for posting.